# Transforming the type of an argument of a function using decorator

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, typing, pyright

I am attempting to transform a certain instance that belongs to type A to type B, but I am stuck at the type annotations (using pyright to type check), I currently have the following:

```py
A = TypeVar("A")
B = TypeVar("B")

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")
P2 = ParamSpec("P2")

def ensure(a: Type[A], convert: Callable[[A], B]
) -> Callable[[Callable[P2, Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]], Callable[P, Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]]:


    def command(func: Callable[P2, Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]) -> Callable[P, Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]:

        async def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            for i, argument in enumerate(args):
                if isinstance(argument, a):
                    new_instance = convert(argument)

                    arguments = (*args[:i], new_instance, *args[i + 1:])
                    return await func(*arguments, **kwargs)
            raise TypeError("Type not found in arguments")

        return wrapper

    return command
```

but it gives me
`error: ParamSpec "P" is scoped to a callable within the return type and cannot be referenced in the function body (reportGeneralTypeIssues)`, which is valid, as well as `Arguments for ParamSpec "P2@command" are missing (reportGeneralTypeIssues)`.

I also tried using Concatenate as below

```py
def ensure(a: Type[A], convert: Callable[[A], B]
) -> Callable[[Callable[Concatenate[B, P], Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]], Callable[Concatenate[A, P], Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]]:


    def command(func: Callable[Concatenate[B, P], Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]) -> Callable[Concatenate[A, P], Coroutine[Any, Any, T]]:

        async def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            for i, argument in enumerate(args):
                if isinstance(argument, a):
                    new_instance = convert(argument)

                    arguments = (*args[:i], new_instance, *args[i + 1:])
                    return await func(*arguments, **kwargs)
            raise TypeError("Type not found in arguments")

        return wrapper

    return command
```

but, I don't know the position of the argument beforehand.

I can't seem to find a solution that demonstrates what I'm trying to do via type hinting, and I would appreciate some guidance in how to go about this?

Edit: Example use case

```py
class UserContext(api.Context):
    
    def __init__(self, ctx: api.Context):
         ...



@api.command()
@ensure(api.Context, UserContext)
async def write(ctx: UserContext, ...):
    ...
```

The API package will then use the write command and passes it an instance of api.Context and the decorator will transform api.Context into UserContext and pass it to the write command.

Comment: The decorated async-function should always be called with _exactly one **positional**_ argument of type `A`? Can you also provide a minimal **usage example** for this decorator showing what types you expect your type checker to infer? Because as it stands right now, I don't understand the purpose of having two parameter specifications.

Comment: ok, I provided an example, in the question. I'm trying to using this for a project to extend an instance that an external package passes into my async function, so I need to intercept it and transform it.

Comment: OK, but the signature of the wrapped function (meaning after decoration with `@ensure`) should still be exactly the same as that of the original (in your example `write`), no? It takes an argument of type `UserContext` plus other arbitrary arguments, with and without the decorator, right?

Comment: No, signature of wrapped function will take an argument of type ``api.Context``. The function within the wrapped function (i.e. if you remove the decorator) is the one with argument type ``UserContext``

Comment: ``write``: UserContext + arguments
``decorated write``: api.Context + arguments

``decorated write`` transforms api.Context -> UserContext and passes it along with the other arguments to ``write``

Comment: OK, in that case `Concatenate` is in fact the way to go and you _have_ to know the position of the parameter beforehand. Otherwise, how would that even work? A signature must have that argument in a certain position. Otherwise there is no signature. There is no such construct as "parameter spec with one parameter of type A, but I don't know which one".